# How to set text characters in cubes horizontally and vertically both

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am making crossword app i want to set my text horizontal & vertical both now its coming in cross align i want to make it vertical android another text to vertical

```
    public class PuzzleView extends View {

    private float width; // width of one tile
    private float height; // height of one tile
    private int selX; // X index of selection
    private int selY; // Y index of selection
    private final Rect selRect = new Rect();

    private final Game game;

    public PuzzleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.game = (Game) context;
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     }

     @Override
     protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        width = w / 9f;
        height = h / 9f;
        getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSizeChanged: width " + width + ", height " + height);
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
     }

     @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Draw the background...
        Paint background = new Paint();
        background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_background));
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);

        // Draw the board...

        // Define colors for the grid lines
        Paint dark = new Paint();
        dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_dark));

        Paint hilite = new Paint();
        hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hilite));

        Paint light = new Paint();
        light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_light));

        // Draw the minor grid lines
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, light);
            canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                    hilite);
            canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), light);
            canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                    hilite);
        }

        // Draw the major grid lines
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i % 3 != 0)
                continue;
            canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height, dark);
            canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1,
                    hilite);
            canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), dark);
            canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight(),
                    hilite);
        }
        // Draw the numbers...

        // Define color and style for numbers
        Paint foreground = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        foreground.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_foreground));
        foreground.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        foreground.setTextSize(height * 0.75f);
        foreground.setTextScaleX(width / height);
        foreground.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        // // Draw the number in the center of the tile
        FontMetrics fm = foreground.getFontMetrics();
        // // Centering in X: use alignment (and X at midpoint)
        float x = width / 2;
        // // Centering in Y: measure ascent/descent first
        float y = height / 2 - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;

        Paint hint = new Paint();

            String str = "TEXT";
            int m;
            for (m = 0; m < str.length(); m++) {
                System.out.println(str.charAt(m));
                char convertst = str.charAt(m);


                String characterToString = Character.toString(convertst);
                //canvas.drawText(characterToString, x, y, hint);
                 canvas.drawText(characterToString, m
                 * width + x, m * height + y, foreground); //its working in cross

                hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                hint.setTextSize(45);
            }

      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);

        select((int) (event.getX() / width), (int) (event.getY() / height));
        game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
        Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: x " + selX + ", y " + selY);
        return true;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onKeyDown: keycode=" + keyCode + ", event=" + event);
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
            select(selX, selY - 1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
            select(selX, selY + 1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            select(selX - 1, selY);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            select(selX + 1, selY);
            break;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
            setSelectedTile(0);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
            setSelectedTile(1);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
            setSelectedTile(2);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
            setSelectedTile(3);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_4:
            setSelectedTile(4);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_5:
            setSelectedTile(5);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_6:
            setSelectedTile(6);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_7:
            setSelectedTile(7);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_8:
            setSelectedTile(8);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_9:
            setSelectedTile(9);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            game.showKeypadOrError(selX, selY);
            break;

        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void setSelectedTile(int tile) {
        if (game.setTileIfValid(selX, selY, tile)) {
            invalidate();// may change hints
        } else {

            // Number is not valid for this tile
            Log.d(TAG, "setSelectedTile: invalid: " + tile);

            startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(game, R.anim.shake));

         }
       }
      private void select(int x, int y) {
        invalidate(selRect);
        selX = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8);
        selY = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8);
        getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
        invalidate(selRect);
      }

      private void getRect(int x, int y, Rect rect) {
        rect.set((int) (x * width), (int) (y * height),
                (int) (x * width + width), (int) (y * height + height));
       }

   }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
     some part of the code  enter code here
                width = w / 9f;
              height = h / 9f;

             float x = width / 2;
                // // Centering in Y: measure ascent/descent first
             float y = height / 2 - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;

      ///  This is the main area where i am handling the position /////

              String str = "TEXT";
            int m;
            for (m = 0; m < str.length(); m++) {
                System.out.println(str.charAt(m));
                char convertst = str.charAt(m);


                String characterToString = Character.toString(convertst);
                 canvas.drawText(characterToString, m
                 * width + x, m * height + y, foreground); //its working in cross

                hint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                hint.setTextSize(45);
            }
```

here is the view i am getting:

[image: here is the view i am getting]

Here is the view i which i want :
[image]

Comment: can you able to provide your working code ?

Comment: its is my working code @Crazy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not increase start parameter.

```
canvas.drawText(characterToString, x, m * height + y, foreground);
```

Comment: cany u suggest me any good tutorial for canvas system in android?